# How to mount and activate the template created in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

How many templates can be created in Apache IoTDB? Without the same physical quantity, are there no relationship between the template mounted on the lower layer node and the upper layer node? How can I mounted and activate the templates in IoTDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple templates can be created in Apache IoTDB, but the mounting and activation are all on the lower nodes, such as creating 2 templates, t1 and t2, and you have a device named `root.db.factory1.d1`, then you can mount t1, t2 on `root.db.factory1.d1.group1` and `root.db.factory1.d1.group2` respectively.